# In Split view controller: Call detailed view controller method from master view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

In my `MasterViewController` `uitabelview` did select method change the `DetailedViewController` view.

My problem is when i change the view in `DetailedViewController` need to save the textfield values if user not saved manually.

How can i check this from `MasterViewController` or any idea to detect master view did select method called from `DetailedViewController`.

thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should implement [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

Comment: can you give some code.

Comment: you want to call a method of `DetailedViewController` from the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of `MasterViewController`, right ?

Comment: yes , your right @Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

in your `MasterViewController.h`

```
@protocol CellSelectionDelegate <NSObject>

     -(void)rowSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end


@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
}
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITableView *menuTable;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CellSelectionDelegate> cellDelegate;

@end
```

in your `MasterViewController.m`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([self.cellDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(rowSelected:)])
    {
        //sending selected indexPath, you can use indexPath.row in your detail view
        [self.cellDelegate rowSelected:indexPath];
    }

}
```

Now in your `DetailedViewController.h`

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
@interface DetailedViewController : UIViewController<CellSelectionDelegate>
{

}
@property(nonatomic,strong)MasterViewController *masterView;
@end
```

in `DetailedViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Set master page as the delegate.
    masterView.delegate = self;

}
```

Now declare following delegate method

```
-(void)rowSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Your selected Row : %d",indexPath.row);
    //do your work according to selection made in master view. use indexpath.row to identify which option was selected, you can also pass the other data with rowselected: method
}
```

Comment: cannot find protocol declaration for CellSelectionDelegate.unable to implement protocol.

Comment: I know this is old, but I just ran into this issue and found I had a circular dependency in my master and detail imports (ie. they were importing each others' headers). Fixing this allowed the delegate to work properly